# Descargar PDF con Selenium-Chrome Driver-Python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

Este código es el resultante de muchas consultas y ensayos de acuerdo a lo encontrado Googleando, pero llego siempre al mismo lugar.

Lo que necesito con este código es entrar al sitio en cuestión llenar 2 datos en el formulario, consultar y luego presionar un botón que abre un pdf. Este código ya hace todo, pero realmente lo que necesito es descargar el PDF... no abrirlo.

PD: el Chrome Option Headless y Sandbox están documentados para ver el proceder, pero realmente los necesito activos para el código final.

Python 2.7, Selenium, Chrome Driver para Navegador 77.8

```py
import os
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.common import exceptions

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#chrome_options.add_argument("no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
#chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
#driver = os.path.join("/opt/odoo/procedimientos/","chromedriver")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": "c:/",
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
  "plugins.plugins_disabled" : ["Chrome PDF Viewer"],
})

driver = os.path.join("c:/Python27/Desarrollos/","chromedriver")

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver,chrome_options=chrome_options)

browser.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')
params = {'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': "c:/"}}
command_result = browser.execute("send_command", params)

browser.get("https://tramites.anm.gov.co/Portal/pages/consultaListados/anonimoListados.jsf")
print(browser.title)


#for ii in ids:
    #print ii.tag_name
    #print ii.get_attribute('class')

#time.sleep(5)

#rol = browser.find_element_by_id("form:trol_focus")
rol = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/form/div/div/div[2]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[3]")
rol.click()

time.sleep(1)

rol = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/ul/li[8]").click()

#rol_label = browser.find_element_by_id("form:trol_label")

#print "ROL: ", rol_label.text

time.sleep(1)

numid = browser.find_element_by_id("form:numId")
numid.clear()
numid.send_keys("1007824403")
#numid.send_keys("8357786")
numid_value = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@id,'form:numId')]").get_attribute('value')

print "NUMID: ", numid_value

boton_buscar = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/form/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/button[1]").click()

time.sleep(2)


if len(browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/form/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/ul/li/span")) > 0:
    print "No se encontro resultados"
else:
    pdf_link = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='form:j_idt34']").click()
```

Comment: Ese form:j_idt34 no tiene un enlace en el HTML? Podrías mejor sacar el enlace directo y descargarlo ya sea por httpRequest directo o wget del S.O.

Comment: El título en inglés sobra.

Answer (score 0):

Este tipo de cosas se pueden controlar desde las opciones, como ya has intentado, las que yo usaria serian las siguientes:

```
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs',{
"download.default_directory": "Directorio de descarga",
"download.prompt_for_download": False, # Para que el navegador no pregunte al descargar
"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True}) # Para que el navegador no abra el PDF en una pestaña nueva
```